# Mismatched SSL certificate in Azure Compute Emulator

Tags: ssl, azure, emulation, mismatch

I have Azure app containing 4 sites in a single web role (differentiated by host headers). I setup the sites to run over SSL. I issued 2 self signed certificates: 1 as CA installed into Trusted Root CAs store and 1 wildcard SSL certificate (issued using the first one).

The application runs, however I'm getting certificate error 'Mismatched address' in Azure Compute Emulator. I examined the mismatched certificate and found out it is not the one specified in service configuration. I went into IIS management console and checked the bindings - there was no cert set for my sites. So I setup the wildcard certificate manually in the site bindings. But in browser I still have mismatched certificate, still the one for 127.0.0.1 (comming with DevFabric). How can I make the IIS to return the correct certificate configured for the site?

(I have some services in the web sites consumed by Silverlight application and it does not work when there is forced manual confirmation of the certificate by user.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you really access the service using https://127.0.0.1 and not using https://localhost?

Comment: I access the service using the host header, e.g.: <https://app.mydomain.com:5172/myservice.svc> and the wildcard certificate is issued to *.mydomain.com. In etc\hosts I defined the mapping from app.mydomain.com to 127.0.0.1. The certificate is set (manualy) in web site bindings.

Comment: Ahh ok. Well I didn't have to mess with web.config to get my service to work with the certificate. All I did was specifying a self-signed certificate issued to localhost using the Azure Properties for my WCF role and be done with it. In production the real certificate you set using the Azure Portal is used automatically.